# How to show related posts by category from different post type

Tags: php, wordpress

In my website, I have two different post-types. One of them is `publication` with custom category-type as `publication-category` and the other is `service` with custom category-type as `service-category`. I am publishing some brochures in Publication page those are under different services. What I am trying to do is displaying these brochures in Services page by same category type. It is like, if the brochure is published by Education services, then this brochure should be displayed in Education service page.

I am currently using ACF plugin to do so, but whenever there is new brochure, I have to go to service page and add it there. Today I tried below code but it displays all brochures from different category-types not the same category-type.

Perhaps you guys can help me how I can arrange the code a way that works for my above request.

```
<?php

$custom_taxterms = wp_get_object_terms( 
    $post->ID, 
    'publication-category', 
    array( 'fields' => 'ids' ) 
);

$args = array(
    'post_type'      => 'publication',
    'post_status'    => 'publish',
    'posts_per_page' => 10,
    'orderby'        => 'rand',
    'order'          => 'ASC',
    'tax_query'      => array( array(
        'taxonomy' => 'publication-category',
        'field'    => 'id',
        'terms'    => $custom_taxterms
    )),
    'post__not_in'   => array( $post->ID ),
);

$related_items = new WP_Query( $args );

if ( $related_items->have_posts() ) :
    echo '<ul>';
    while ( $related_items->have_posts() ) : $related_items->the_post();
    ?>
        <li><a href="<?php the_permalink(); ?>"><?php the_title(); ?></a></li>
    <?php
    endwhile;
    echo '</ul>';
endif;

wp_reset_postdata();
?>
```

Comment: I am not following your requirement. Are you saying that you would have an `'Education services'` term in both `publication-category` and in `'service-category'`. I also do not understand what you are asking with these sentences: _"I am publishing some brochures in Publication page those are under different services."_ and _"What I am trying to do is displaying these brochures in Services page by same category type."_ And what theme template page are you trying to create; `single-service.php`?

Comment: @MikeSchinkel, I have already created theme template page for both services `single-services.php` and publications `single-publication.php` page. Also, I have registered _taxonomy_ separately for both template pages. Under _services_ page, we have education, recruiting, and consulting services and we share brochures in publication page. when we share any publication, we state the service name in the publication by using taxonomy type. So, I want to create relationship between these two template pages to display publications in individual service pages by category type. I hope it is clear.

Comment: So you linked them with ACF field relationship?

Comment: @Stender, yes i am currently using ACF to link them, but every time when I have new publication shared, I have to go to that particular service page and add that publication in ACF custom field. So I want to make it automated by creation relationship between the category-types.

Comment: I am realizing that what you need is someone who knows ACF, which I do not. So can’t help in this case.

Comment: @MikeSchinkel, so without plugin we cannot create this relationship?

Comment: ahh - okay, so you want to go away from ACF, and make it automated

Comment: Are you asking to get rid of ACF, as @Stender is asking?

Comment: @MikeSchinkel, yes I have stated above too. I am currently using ACF but whenever I add new brochure in to Publication page, I have to go to Service page and linking that new publication to the service page. So it takes time and some times, I forget it.

Comment: I am sorry. I am struggling to understand exactly what you want.  To automate relationships or to completely remove and replace ACF?  If the former, I can't help. If the latter, that's too big a scope for me to help in this issue. Sorry.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I find the solution by changing service-category taxonomy to publication-category as same with other post-type and creating relationship with below code from : https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/139571/display-posts-with-same-taxonomy-term?rq=1

Thanks everyone

```
  <?php
                                          //get the post's venues
                                      $custom_terms = wp_get_post_terms($post->ID, 'publication-category');

                                      if( $custom_terms ){

                                          // going to hold our tax_query params
                                          $tax_query = array();

                                          // add the relation parameter (not sure if it causes trouble if only 1 term so what the heck)
                                          if( count( $custom_terms > 1 ) )
                                              $tax_query['relation'] = 'OR' ;

                                          // loop through venus and build a tax query
                                          foreach( $custom_terms as $custom_term ) {

                                              $tax_query[] = array(
                                                  'taxonomy' => 'publication-category',
                                                  'field' => 'slug',
                                                  'terms' => $custom_term->slug,
                                              );

                                          }

                                          // put all the WP_Query args together
                                          $args = array( 'post_type' => 'publication',
                                                          'posts_per_page' => 20,
                                                          'tax_query' => $tax_query );

                                          // finally run the query
                                          $loop = new WP_Query($args);

                                          if( $loop->have_posts() ) {

                                              while( $loop->have_posts() ) : $loop->the_post(); ?>

                                              <div class="listing-title"><?php the_title(); ?></div>
                                            <div class="listing-image"><a href="<?php the_permalink() ?>" style="background-image: url('<?php echo get_the_post_thumbnail_url(get_the_ID(), 'full') ?>')"></a>
                                            </div>
                                              <?php

                                              endwhile;

                                          }

                                          wp_reset_query();

                                      }?>
```

Answer (score 0):

If you're on services page, so why do you use the 'publication-category' in

```
wp_get_object_terms( 
    $post->ID, 
    'publication-category', 
    array( 'fields' => 'ids' ) 
);
```

Seems like you have to use

```
$custom_taxterms = get_the_terms($post->ID, 'service-category');

$terms = [];
foreach ($custom_taxterms as $term) {
  $terms[] = $term->slug
}

$args = array(
    'post_type'      => 'publication',
    'post_status'    => 'publish',
    'posts_per_page' => 10,
    'orderby'        => 'rand',
    'order'          => 'ASC',
    'tax_query'      => array( array(
        'taxonomy' => 'publication-category',
        'field'    => 'slug',
        'terms'    => $terms
    )),
);
```

And create same slugs for both terms in both categories. From my understanding. It's quite difficult to understand your architecture